# Hanoi move func. in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I saw one answer in another post:

```
type Position = Int
type Move = (Position,Position) 
type Towers = ([Int],[Int],[Int])

hanoi 1 i j = [(i,j)] 
hanoi n i j = hanoi n' i otherT ++ [(i,j)] ++ hanoi n' otherT j 
      where n' = n-1 
            otherT = 1+2+3-i-j -- other tower

move ::([Move],Towers) -> ([Move],Towers) 
move ([],(xs,ys,zs) ) = ((error "Error"),(xs,ys,zs) ) 
move (((a,b): tail), (xs,ys,zs) ) | a > 3 = (tail, ((error "Error"),ys,zs) )
       | b > 3 = (tail, ((error "Error"),ys,zs ) )
       | otherwise = hilfsfunktion (((a,b): tail), (xs,ys,zs) )

hilfsfunktion (((1,2): tail), ((x:xs),(y:ys),zs) )
       | x < y = (tail, (xs, (x:y:ys),zs) ) 
       | x > y = (tail, (xs, (error "too big"),(error "too big")))        

hilfsfunktion (((1,2): tail), ((x:xs), [],zs) ) = (tail, (xs, x:[],zs) )
```

corrected one :

```
all_moves :: ([Move], Towers) -> Towers
all_moves ([], (xs, ys, zs)) = (xs, ys, zs)
all_moves movetowers = all_moves (move movetowers)
```

But I can't make it work in haskell.

```
*Main> move(it, ([1,2,3],[],[])) 
*** Exception: Tu.hs:(19,1)-(22,72): Non-exhaustive patterns in function hilfsfunktion
```

My questions:

1. Does this need more corrections?
2. How does `(a,b):tail` work here?

Comment: you implemented the `hilfsfunktion` only for moves from *tower* (I guess) 1 to 2 - but there are a some more!

Comment: here you can find a [simplified version](https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/e8a569115a370245f0a4) - maybe you'll find it interesting

Comment: That helps a lot. But I am trying to do here is: 1, to have a function for move :: ([Move],Towers) -> ([Move],Towers) , which which gets a list of moves and a game configuration, checks the first move and then executes. and then 2, the function for all_moves :: ([Move], Towers) -> Towers.

Comment: maybe you'll like the [older version](https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/3f54a312132d6d7d2051) there I had something like this (but it's double the size and not very elegant) - you will find `move` there which will try to make a single move

Answer (score 2):

First thing is, you have fallen into a common mistake of novice Haskellers; thinking that all function arguments should be in brackets, like this:

```
foo (a, b, c) = ....
```

In most languages this would be a three-argument function. In Haskell its a function that takes a single argument consisting of a three-element tuple. You ought to write

```
foo a b c = ....
```

This avoids extraneous brackets and makes life much easier when you start using higher order functions.

Now on to the meat of your question:

Your hilfsfunktion defines two cases. In both of those cases the first list in the argument has to start with the element (1,2). If you pass anything else in then it will fail to match either of the cases, and hence causes the exception message you got.

Comment: Like this ?    x < y =  (1,2):tail     xs, (x:y:ys),zs  . But still, the problem remains.

Comment: No, the problem lies in the pattern "hilfsfunktion (((1,2): tail) ....". Read up on pattern matching in functions; I don't think you understand what you have written.